# Using `emacsclient` for `$VISUAL` raises `End of file during parsing`

Tags: emacsclient, bash

I want to use emacs as `VISUAL` with server-mode.  As a test, I write the following in a terminal:

```
emacsclient -F "((left . 0) (top . 0))" -c -n file
```

This behaves exactly as expected; it opens my file `file` in GUI window with the right geometry, exactly the behaviour I want from `$VISUAL filename`.  So I add the following line to the end of my `.bashrc`:

```
export VISUAL='emacsclient -F "((left . 0) (top . 0))" -c -n file'
```

Now I test this from a terminal:

```
$ source .bashrc
$ $VISUAL file
*ERROR*: End of file during parsing
```

I recognize that as an error thrown by emacs when it evaluates elisp with mismatched delimiters.  I thought at first that I might be doing something wrong with single and double quotes, but this doesn't explain the error; emacs is starting, but somewhere it's running into some problem with a mismatched delimiter.

**Question:** (1) Why is emacs throwing an error when called from `$VISUAL` like this, despite the fact that the command itself works correctly?  (2) How do I fix it?

P.S. I'm on `GNU Emacs 26.3` and `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`; thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how the shell expands `$VISUAL`. When the shell expands a variable outside of double quotes (`$VISUAL` as opposed to `"$VISUAL"`), it splits the value into words (and treats each word as a shell wildcard pattern, but that's not relevant here). So it runs the command `emacsclient` with the arguments `-F`, `"((left . 0)`, `(top . 0))"`, `-c`, `-n`, `file`, `file`. The error message you're seeing comes from parsing `"((left . 0)` which is an unterminated string.

There's no standard for the syntax of `VISUAL`: some applications use the equivalent of running `$VISUAL filename` in a shell, while others use the equivalent of taking the value of `VISUAL`, appending the (quoted) file name and running the result through a shell (which would do what you want), and there are even other cases (I've seen applications that want `VISUAL` to be a path to an executable file with no arguments, but that's uncommon). So you should keep it simple. If you need to pass arguments with spaces, use a wrapper script.

In my configuration, I use

```
export VISUAL="$HOME/bin/EDITOR"
```

and I have a script called `EDITOR` that dispatches to emacslient (and for me also has a fallback if Emacs isn't installed). For you that wrapper script would be

```
#!/bin/sh
exec emacsclient -F "((left . 0) (top . 0))" -c -n "$@"
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except that I need to explicitly write the path of `$HOME` for some reason.  It seems the heart of my problems go a little deeper into `gnome-terminal` as well.  Thanks for fixing my emacs query!

Comment: Nope, nevermind: I forgot I was on a login shell...  I am my own worst enemy :)  Thanks again very much!